# Beginner Java Scope Issue

Tags: java, scope

I'm new to programming and seem to be running into issues with when a variable, class, etc can and can't be referenced. Below is an example, hoping one of you can fix the specific issue but also help me understand it more broadly so I don't run into it again and again.

to try and avoid posting a bunch of code please note that a Question class is defined as well as a setText, setAnswer, checkAnswer,  and display method are all defined elsewhere (all public).

The relevant code is below and I have two questions:

1. Why is the variable `first` not recognized in the method `presentQuestion()`?
2. At the very end there, why can't I just call the method `checkAnswer()` on first, i.e. why can't I just do `first.checkAnswer(response);`? Why do I have to define it in a new variable: `boolean outcome = first.checkAnswer(response);`?

Code:

```
/**
 * This program shows a simple quiz with two questions.
 */

public class QuestionDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        Question first = new Question();
        first.setText("Who was the inventor of Java?");
        first.setAnswer("James Gosling");

        Question second = new Question();
        second.setText("Who was the founder of Udacity?");
        second.setAnswer("Sebastian Thrun");

        int score = 0;
        score = score + presentQuestion(first, in);
        // Present the second question
        score = score + presentQuestion(second, in);
        System.out.println("Your score: " + score);
    }

    /**
     * Presents a question to the user and obtains a response.
     * @param q the question to present
     * @param in the scanner from which to read the user input
     * @return the score (1 if correct, 0 if incorrect);
     */
    public static int presentQuestion(Question q, Scanner in) {
        // Display the first question
        first.display();
        System.out.println("Your answer:");
        String response = in.nextLine();
        // Check whether the response was correct
        // If so, print "true" and return 1
        // Otherwise, print "false" and return 0
        boolean outcome = first.checkAnswer(response);
        System.out.println(outcome);
        if (outcome) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't use the variable `first` inside `presentQuestion` is because it's defined in `main`, and therefore not visible outside of `main`. Isn't this precisely why you gave `presentQuestion` its `Question q` parameter, however?

It seems to me that this is what you want to do:

```
public static int presentQuestion(Question q, Scanner in)
{
    // Display the first question
    q.display();
    System.out.println("Your answer:");
    String response = in.nextLine();
    // Check whether the response was correct
    // If so, print "true" and return 1
    // Otherwise, print "false" and return 0
    boolean outcome = q.checkAnswer(response);
    System.out.println(outcome);
    if (outcome) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Note that references to `first` have been replaced by references to `q`.

To try and clear up what I imagine your confusion may consist in, imagine if `presentQuestion` were called from another method than `main`, in which case no `first` variable would be declared at all. What would then happen to the references to `first` inside of `presentQuestion`, now not referring to anything at all? This is why you need to explicitly pass the data you want as parameters. Different methods are *independent* blocks of code, and you can't intermingle variable references between them even if they happen to call each other.

As for question 2, there should indeed be no problem with checking `if(q.checkAnswer(response))` directly, without using the `outcome` variable. I'm guessing you were simply confused by the error emitted by the compiler when `first` wasn't recognized again.

Comment: Thanks so much Dolda (and everyone else that answered). I really didn't properly understand parameters it seems and this really is a big step-up in my understanding. code works now and I actually understand why so thanks again

Answer (score 0):

1. `first` is a *local variable*, that means it can only be accessed inside the method in which it is defined.
2. You don't have to put the result of `checkAnswer()` into a boolean before using it. Actually, `if (checkAnswer(response)) { ... }` is valid.

Answer (score 0):

`presentQuestion` takes a question as a parameter.  In `main`, you're calling it on the first question, and then on the second question; it looks like the intent is that you use `presentQuestion` on the first question, and then on the second question.  So far, so good.

The problem is that in `presentQuestion`, you're referring to the question (which could be the first or the second question) as `q` in the parameter list.  All you need to do is use `q` instead of `first` in the rest of the method.

Answer (score 0):

When I was new to programming, I had this problem as well! Then I found out it is *very* simple.

For your first question, `first` is declared in the `main` method and you want to use it in `presentQuestion` method. But `presentQuestion` and `main` are different methods! So you can't get to `first` in `presentQuestion`. As you can see, there is a `Question`-typed parameter in the `presentQuestion` method. This is like you telling `first`, "Come here, man! And then change your name to `q`." When you do pass the argument `first` to `presentQuestion`,

```
presentQuestion (first, in);
```

`first` comes to the `pressentQuestion` method with its name being as `q`. So you should use `q` instead of `first` in the `presentQuestion` method.

Now the second question, using a variable in this context is not needed. But to increase efficiency, use a boolean variable to store the result of `checkAnswer`. Let's imagine what happens if you don't use a boolean variable.

```
System.out.println(q.checkAnswer(response));
    if (q.checkAnswer(response)) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
```

See? you called `q.checkAnswer` *twice*! This would slow down your program so you should use a boolean variable.